# Functions strictly monotone increasing and monotone increasing

Tags: calculus, functions, monotone-functions

How can I gather if a function is strictly monotone increasing thus is monotone increasing? Only using the two definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A $ be a subset of $\Bbb R $.

If $f $ is strictly increasing at $A $, then
$$(\forall (x,y)\in A^2)\;(x\ne y\implies \frac {f (x)-f (y)}{x-y}>0)$$

and
$$(\forall (x,y)\in A^2)\;\;(x\ne y \implies \frac {f (x)-f (y)}{x-y}\ge 0)$$

$\implies \; f $ is increasing at $A $.

Answer (score 0):

If a function $f$ is strictly monotone increasing then for $x, y$ such that $x < y$, $f(x) < f(y)$, so $f(x) \le f(y)$ so $f$ is monotone increasing.

Answer (score 0):

For 
$\Delta x = x' - x \gt 0$, 
and
$\Delta f(x) = f(x') - f(x)$

$\Delta f(x) \gt 0$ implies strictly increasing

$\Delta f(x) \lt 0$ implies strictly decreasing

$\Delta f(x) \geq 0$ implies increasing

$\Delta f(x) \leq 0$ implies decreasing

In other words, if $f'(x)$ does not change sign over the interval, then the function is monotone.

Comment: If the derivative of $f$ is meant by $f'(x)$ you should also mind functions that cannot be differentiated in some points. Example: $f(x)=x-sgn(x)$

Comment: Correct, I was just mentioning that as a side note for intuition when a derivative exists $\forall x$ .